# python pandas with to_sql() , SQLAlchemy and schema in exasol

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to upload a pandas data frame to an SQL table. It seemed to me that pandas to_sql function is the best solution for larger data frames, but I can't get it to work. I can easily extract data, but get an error message when trying to write it to a new table:

```py
# connect to Exasol DB
exaString='DSN=exa'
conDB = pyodbc.connect(exaString)   

# get some data from somewhere, works without error
sqlString = "SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE"
data = pd.read_sql(sqlString, conDB)

# now upload this data to a new table
data.to_sql('MYTABLENAME', conDB, flavor='mysql')

conDB.close()
```

The error message I get is

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [EXASOL][EXASolution driver]syntax error, unexpected identifier_chain2, expecting
>   assignment_operator or ':' [line 1, column 6] (-1)
>   (SQLExecDirectW)")

Unfortunately I have no idea how the query that caused this syntax error looks like or what else is wrong. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

**(Second) EDIT:**

Following Humayuns and  Joris suggestions, I now use Pandas version 0.14 and SQLAlchemy in combination with the Exasol dialect (?). Since I am connecting to a defined schema, I am using the meta data option, but the programm crashes with "Bus error (core dumped)".

```py
engine = create_engine('exa+pyodbc://uid:passwd@exa/mySchemaName', echo=True)    

# get some data
sqlString = "SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE"    # SOMETABLE is a view in mySchemaName 
df = pd.read_sql(sqlString, con=engine)  # works

print engine.has_table('MYTABLENAME')    # MYTABLENAME is a view in mySchemaName
# prints "True"

# upload it to a new table
meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(engine, schema='mySchemaName')
meta.reflect(engine, schema='mySchemaName')
pdsql = sql.PandasSQLAlchemy(engine, meta=meta)
pdsql.to_sql(df, 'MYTABLENAME')
```

I am not sure about setting "mySchemaName" in create_engine(..), but the outcome is the same.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? Furthermore, I don't think this database flavor is supported in older pandas versions (only sqlite and mysql were). From pandas 0.14, the function uses SQLAlchemy to support different flavors.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am using pandas version 0.13.1. I also followed your suggestion to use sqlalchemy with this https://github.com/blue-yonder/sqlalchemy_exasol , but still cannot get it to run (see my edit).

Comment: To use sqlalchemy, you need at least pandas 0.14 (there was a refactor of the sql functions in that pandas version to use sqlalchemy), so it will not work with 0.13.1. And if you use it, you need to provide the engine itself, and not a connection. So I think the only option is to upgrade to pandas 0.14, but I cannot guarantee it will work then, because AFAIK it was never tested with exa (and for that reason it would be very interesting to try).

Comment: And using `df.to_sql('MYTABLENAME', engine)` also leads to this error? Can you give a more full traceback? Specifying schema's is currently not really supported (see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7441), but hopefully this will improve in 0.15. It is also possible that it is a bug in the exasol-sqlalchemy dialect, I never used this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas does not support the EXASOL syntax out of the box, so it need to be changed a bit, here is a working example of your code without SQLAlchemy:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

con = pyodbc.connect('DSN=EXA')
con.execute('OPEN SCHEMA TEST2')

# configure pandas to understand EXASOL as mysql flavor
pd.io.sql._SQL_TYPES['int']['mysql'] = 'INT'
pd.io.sql._SQL_SYMB['mysql']['br_l'] = ''
pd.io.sql._SQL_SYMB['mysql']['br_r'] = ''
pd.io.sql._SQL_SYMB['mysql']['wld'] = '?'
pd.io.sql.PandasSQLLegacy.has_table = \
    lambda self, name: name.upper() in [t[0].upper() for t in con.execute('SELECT table_name FROM cat').fetchall()]

data = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM services', con)
data.to_sql('SERVICES2', con, flavor = 'mysql', index = False)
```

If you use the EXASolution Python package, then the code would look like follows:

```
import exasol
con = exasol.connect(dsn='EXA') # normal pyodbc connection with additional functions
con.execute('OPEN SCHEMA TEST2')

data = con.readData('SELECT * FROM services') # pandas data frame per default
con.writeData(data, table = 'services2')
```

Comment: As a tip, with EXASolution 5.0 you will get a EXASolution Python package, which has a native and match faster implementation of this functionality (read_sql and to_sql) in pure python.

Comment: This is indeed also a possibility if it does not yet work with SQLAlchemy, although I don't recommend it as it is not really guaranteed that this will keep working in the future

Comment: Yes, its true, currently the best solution to transfer data between EXASolution and Pandas objects is to use the EXASolution Python package, it is also much faster.

Comment: Maybe you can give an example how to do it with this package? That would be usefull as a reference.

Comment: Sure, i have added it now to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, your SQLAlchmey solution worked for me! I cannot use EXASolution as an option right now, but will definitely try it as soon as it is available on our system.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that also in pandas 0.14 the read_sql and to_sql functions cannot deal with schemas, but using exasol without schemas makes no sense. This will be fixed in 0.15. If you want to use it now look at this pull request https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7952

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I will definitely try the now pandas version!

Comment: Update: starting from pandas 0.15, writing to different schema's is supported. Then you will be able to use the `schema` keyword argument: ``df.to_sql('test', engine, schema='a_schema')``